# A positive integer is special if it has at least two proper divisors and is a multiple of all possible differences between two of them.

Tags: number-theory

> The proper divisors of a positive integer n are all positive integers other than 1 and n which divide $n$. A positive integer is special if it has at least two proper divisors and is a multiple of all possible differences between two of them. Determine all positive integers that are special.

I determined that $6$,$8$ and $12$ are special. And that any power of $2$ greater that $8$ is not special. But I don't know how to proceed, I would appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: Do you think odd numbers can be special? Once you've answered that question, consider the implications for even numbers.

Comment: Well, somethings seem obvious.  Can you prove that all special numbers are even, for example?

Comment: Ok, so keep going.  What can you say about even special numbers?

Comment: Suppose $p$ is the least odd prime dividing a special $n$.  What is $p$?

Comment: For problems like this, you have to just keep trying things.  Minimal effort should show you that special $n>12$ are divisible by $12$ and that means...?  At least you should be able to show that the next special one is quite a bit larger than $12$.

Comment: So, now keep going.  Like I said, this sort of problem just requires effort and flexibility.

Comment: I don't understand.  Try something simpler.  Assuming $n>12$ we list the primes that divide $n$:   $p_1, \cdots, p_k$.  Then consider $\prod p_i-4$.

Answer (score 5):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

Let's argue that there are no special numbers $>12$.  Toward that end, suppose that $n$ is one.

Elementary considerations show that $n$ is divisible by (at least) $2^3\times 3^2\times 5\times 7$.

(Pf:  $n $ can't be odd since the difference of two odd factors would be even. Easy to rule out powers of $2$ greater than $8$, as they would be divisible by $8-2=6$.  Thus $n$ is divisible by an odd prime.  Let $p$ be the least such.  Then $p-2$ is odd and must be $1$, else there's a smaller odd prime dividing $n$.  Hence $p=3$ so $3\,|\,n$.  It follows that $6\,|\,n$.  Hence $6-2=4$ divides $n$.  Hence $4\times 3=12\,|\,n$.  Hence $12-3=9$ divides $n$, as does $12-4=8$.  Furthermore, $8-3=5, 9-2=7$ divides $n$.  And we are done).

Let $p_1, \cdots, p_k$ be the distinct primes which divide $n$ and let $P=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i$ be their product.  Then, of course $P\,|\,n$.  Now, $P\neq n$ since $4\,\nmid P$.  Thus, the fact that $n$ is special means that $(P-4)\,|\,n$.  But $P-4>2$ and it is not divisible by $4$, hence it is divisible by some odd prime $q$. Then $q\,|\,n$ but $q\not \in \{p_i\}$, hence we have a contradiction.  And we are done.